# How do I add on/off button to Raspberry Pi Zero?

Tags: raspbian, boot, hardware

How do I add an on/off button to a Raspberry Pi Zero board? I am new to the platform and kindly ask for instructions suitable for a novice. Thank you.

Comment: Why? What is the objective? Do none of the hundred similar questions not provide an answer?

Comment: Please clarify: Do you want a button to shut the pi down/turn it back on or a button to disconnect power/reconnect power?

Answer (score 3):

You can follow this guide on [adding a Power Button to your Raspberry Pi](https://howchoo.com/g/mwnlytk3zmm/how-to-add-a-power-button-to-your-raspberry-pi). It shows how to do it on an RPi 3 model, but you can do exactly the same on the RPi Zero, as their [pinout](https://pinout.xyz/) is the same.

The only caveat with your RPi model is the soldering. Here is a video from the Raspberry Pi Foundation on [how to solder pins to your RPi Zero](https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/getting-started-soldering/). And here is another guide on [how to add 40-pin GPIO connector](https://dronebotworkshop.com/soldering-raspberry-pi-zero-gpio/).

### Edit

If the guide to add a power button is down, here is a [copy of it on Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20201109205941/https://howchoo.com/g/mwnlytk3zmm/how-to-add-a-power-button-to-your-raspberry-pi).

Answer (score -2):

Adding an on/off is fairly simple IF you can solder pretty good.  However, depending on where the Pi is located, you could get on of the usb cables that come with a on/off switch.  They are fairly cheap and come in various links.  I have a couple that I use EVEN though I poweroff the pi.

Comment: I can solder pretty good but it doesn't help me with your answer. What should I solder?

Comment: A power switch on the USB cable is no good if the OP wants the pi to shut down when the button is pressed.

Comment: @scitronbon, GREAT point.  I did not grasp his initial point, I was only thinking of just removing the power after using shutdown command.  I think that David's post answers his question.